# How do I get the GPS icon to show in the status bar in CM7?

Tags: cyanogenmod, gps, htc-droid-incredible, notification-bar

Just did a fresh install of CM7 in my Incredible, it's fantastic, but whenever I turn on my GPS, it does not show in the status bar that it's on, like it does in the stock 2.2 OS.

Is there a way to enable this show it shows when it's active?

Comment: Are you actively using an app that needs the GPS? It usually only displays while it is in use, open Google Maps and see what you find.

Comment: Indeed that does work. Is there anyway to display that it's on? I've accidentally left it on before without realizing it, and I'm used to seeing it in the status bar.

Comment: Not an answer, just a comment - leaving GPS enabled isn't going to have a significant impact on battery life, since it will sit idle until you run an app that requests GPS location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will only show up if you open up an application that will use the GPS for something. For example just open up Google Maps. If you want to know if you left the GPS activated, just slide the notification panel and at the top you will have the toggle buttons, one of them is the GPS.